# oneclick event handler isn't executed

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page title</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

        function oneClick ()
        {
         document.write ( "oneClick () executed." );
        }
</script>

</head>
<body>

<input id = "button1" type = "button" value = "click" oneclick = "oneClick ()" />

</body>
</html>
```

after clicking on the button nothing happens, i think oneClick () isn't executed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`oneclick` event handler name should be `onclick`

Answer (score 4):

oneclick is onclick

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Page title</title> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 

        function oneClick () 
        { 
         document.write ( "oneClick () executed." ); 
        } 
</script> 

</head> 
<body> 

<input id = "button1" type = "button" value = "click" onclick = "oneClick ()" /> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input id = "button1" type = "button" value = "click" onclick = "oneClick();" />
```

it should work fine now.
replace oneclick with onclick=""